Shimano STX RC brake holders compatible with Deore-style pads?
I have some old Shimano cantilever STX RC brake holders, and I want to replace them with some koolstop salmon pads. These Deore LX inserts look pretty similar to the brake pads currently in the holders, but I would like to verify that they will fit my brake holders. Are they compatible?
Edit: These are the same model of brake calipers and holders that I have:


What exactly do you have? I assune it is a V brake and not a straight-pull canti brake. Can you show a picture? Be careful that some brake pads and holders are curved and some straight.

Kool Stop provide the dimensions. Is the length the same as the part you wish to replace? It really is that easy!

@VladimirFГероямслава it is a straight-pull canti brake. I've added an image from the Internet (it's the same model of brake).

You know that Shimano stopped making these pads over ten years ago. The STX and the LX were the same, I have both types of shoe here. But you still have to measure to check the Koool Stop pads will fit. So it's the same problem. Get your ruler out.

They turned out to be compatible. Check the picture of the STX brake shoes with the Koolstop Deore LX salmon brake pads:

